# Array_Push and access associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I'm working with php and mongodb and trying create and push data into associative array

```
$userid = array();
```

I would like to see this

```
$userid = array("1" => 0, "2" => 0, "3" => 0, and so on...);
```

When I fetch column in mongodb called $column["created_at"] by foreach loop
, I'm checking the array weather its empty if it is, add data into array

```
if(is_null($userid[$column["created_at"]])){
    array_push($userid, [$column["created_at"]]);
    $userid[$column["created_at"]] = 0;
}
```

so, is it correct? and How can I access a array for example, I would like to access $userid["1"] 
is it return 0

and What is different between access array by

```
$userid["1"]
```

and,

```
$userid[1];
```

I'm not sure that it would be wrong that $userid[1] maybe access key "2" which has a value 0

*My purpose is keeping no.login each userid by using "created_at" column

Comment: why are you setting `$column["created_at"]` as key inside `$userid`? thats supposed to be `$column['user_id']` right?

Comment: oh sorry, My purpose is keeping no.login each userid by using "created_at" column

Comment: so the purpose of this `$userid` is to have that information contained inside the array right? so the `user_id` should be the keys. the key-pair will be `key = user_id, value = number of times the user has logged in`. is this correct?